# Problem on implicit functions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm asked in Ted Shifrin's Textbook Multivariable Mathematics to :

Suppose $h: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{C^1}$ and $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_2} \neq 0$. Show that the equation $h \begin{pmatrix}y/x \\z/x \end{pmatrix}=0$ defines $z$  $\\$ (locally) implicitly as a $\mathcal{C^1}$ function $z= \phi \begin{pmatrix}x \\y \end{pmatrix} $,

This is easy enough: I fix a $x \neq 0$, use the first assumption and then apply the implicit function Theorem.

However I'm also asked to show that $$x \ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} + y \ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} = \phi \begin{pmatrix}x \\y \end{pmatrix}$$

Which has me stuck. I thought about trying to show that the equation of the tangent plane at $\begin{pmatrix}x \\y \end{pmatrix}$ is zero at the point $\pmb 0$ but I can't go further than that.
$$\\$$

Edit after Ted Shifrin asked me to.

Since $h$ does change as we wiggle $x_2$ we can fix $x \neq 0$ to obtain a continuous one to one onto function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, namely: $z/x$, and so we know that if we wiggle $z$ then $h \begin{pmatrix}y/x \\z/x \end{pmatrix}$ changes too (the partial derivative isn't zero) using the previous fact. This, together with the assumptions in the exercise about $h$, let us deduce that there is a $\mathcal{C^1}$ function $\phi \begin{pmatrix}x \\y \end{pmatrix} = z$ .

The equation of the tangent plane of the graph of $\phi$ at $\pmb x$ is:
$$g\begin{pmatrix}v \\ w \end{pmatrix}= \phi\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix}+ D\phi\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}v-x\\ w-y \end{pmatrix}$$
So, evaluating $g$ at $\pmb 0$ we obtain:

$$g\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}= \phi\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix}+ D\phi\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-x\\ -y \end{pmatrix}$$

$$g\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+ D\phi\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y \end{pmatrix} = \phi\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$$

But I can't show how $g\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=0$

Comment: FYI - @TedShifrin is a regular contributor to this forum.

Comment: I know but I haven't seen him in a while.

Comment: I don't understand fixing $x$.  Please edit to show how you’re applying the Implicit Function Theorem. And I certainly don’t see how the origin makes sense in this question.

Comment: Hello Professor @TedShifrin, I've edited the Question as you asked.

Comment: Hmm ... Can we please see explicitly how the hypothesis of the Implicit Function Theorem gives an explicit conclusion? How in the world did it "let us deduce" that $z=\phi(x,y)$? You do *not* want to be thinking of tangent planes, ultimately.

Comment: When you say $\frac {\partial h}{\partial x}, \frac {\partial h}{\partial y}$, do you mean the derivatives of $h \begin{pmatrix}y/x \\z/x \end{pmatrix}$ with respect to $x, y$, or do you mean $\frac {\partial h}{\partial x_1} \begin{pmatrix}y/x \\z/x \end{pmatrix}, \frac {\partial h}{\partial x_2} \begin{pmatrix}y/x \\z/x \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair It's a typo, I meant to write $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}$

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't understand, by definition $h$ is $\mathcal{C^1}$, $h \begin{pmatrix}y/x \\z/x \end{pmatrix}=0$ and I showed how $\frac{\partial h}{\partial z} \begin{pmatrix}y/x \\z/x \end{pmatrix} \neq 0$, it follows by the implicit function theorem that there is a function $\phi(x,y)=z$. Am I missing something? If you have a hint I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $\dfrac{\partial h}{\partial x_2}\ne 0$, the Implicit Function Theorem tells us that *locally* we can express the level curve $h(x_1,x_2)=0$ as a graph $x_2 = F(x_1)$ for some smooth function $F$. Substituting $x_1=y/x$ and $x_2=z/x$, we get $\frac zx = F\big(\frac yx)$, so we have
$$z=\phi(x,y)= xF(\frac yx),$$
with $F$ smooth and hence $\phi$ smooth.
Now we just differentiate this equation (using product and chain rule), obtaining
$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x} = F(\tfrac yx) -\frac yx F'(\tfrac yx) \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y} = F'(\tfrac yx).$$
Now the rest is easy.

An alternative solution is to define $g(x,y,z)=(\frac yx,\frac zx)$ and set $H(x,y,z) = (h\circ g)(x,y,z)$. Now apply the chain rule to $H$ and use the implicit function theorem to show that since $\partial H/\partial z\ne 0$, we can locally express the level surface $H(x,y,z)=0$ as $z=\phi(x,y)$ for a smooth function $\phi$. This approach is good practice with the techniques.

Answer (score 1):

If one naively ignores all the possible pitfalls and differentiates the equation $h(y/x, z/x) = 0$ (pardon, but I'm not a fan of the vertical notation), which must be true of all $x, y$ within some neighborhood, one gets:

$$0 = \frac{\partial h(y/x, z/x)}{\partial y} = h_1\frac 1x + h_2\frac 1x\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\\\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = -\frac{h_1}{h_2}$$
Where $h_1$ and $h_2$ are the partial derivatives of $h$ with respect to $x_1, x_2$, respectively, and evaluated at $(y/x, z/x)$. And
$$0 = \frac{\partial h(y/x, z/x)}{\partial x} = -h_1\frac y{x^2} + h_2\dfrac{x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} - z}{x^2}\\z = -\frac{h_1}{h_2}y + x\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$
substituting from the previous equation,
$$z = y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} + x \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$$

Of course, it needs some clean up and care to make sure all the "i"s are dotted and all the "t"s crossed, but the basic calculation is there.

Comment: I don't use the vertical notation here (or in a "regular" multivariable calculus class), but I did it for pedagogical reasons in my multivariable math text because of the simultaneous treatment with linear algebra *and* so that students would not mess up rows and columns when it comes to, say, the Jacobian matrix. It really helps.

Comment: Ah! you used implicit differentiation. thx Paul, but I'll have to think about you answer for a bit.

Comment: @TedShifrin - no problem. I'm just an old dog who didn't want to mess with the new trick.